# Running Rails+Passenger+Devise from a subdirectory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, devise, passenger, omniauth

I have a server A which proxies all traffic on `/rails` to server B.

So I setup this virtual host, and most things work...okay. `link_to` is broken and generates urls to `/users` as opposed to `/rails/users`, but I can work around that.

If I set `config.action_controller.relative_url_root` to `/rails` then my routes work okay EXCEPT all the devise routes. They point to the bare URL. How do I properly configure server B to understand that its running in a subdirectory and generate links and routes correctly?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://ec2-url.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
    SetEnv RDS_HOSTNAME "mydb..."
    SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT "/rails"

    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/myapp/public
    RailsEnv staging 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app.log combined
    PassengerLogLevel 3
    <Directory "/home/ubuntu/myapp/public">
 Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Options -MultiViews
   Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am using Rails 4.

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your environment files, add a config for `OmniAuth.config.full_host`.

`OmniAuth.config.full_host = 'http://myfullurl/subdir'`

Now, in `application_controller.rb`, add this method:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    path = super(resource_or_scope)
    "#{OmniAuth.config.full_host}#{path}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you share your `routes.rb`, but I think the easy way to change devise routes is to put something like the following in `routes.rb`

```
scope '/rails' do
  devise_for :users
end
```

Comment: This creates routes like /rails/rails

Comment: I don't understand. First you say that devise is creating routes like '/' (they point to bare URL). And with scope it generates a double scope???

Comment: @StefanKendall Try the following: http://quickhack.net/nom/blog/2012-09-19-rails-with-relative-url-root.html  is in japanese but the examples are in plain english

Comment: I had just that and link_to and the callback URLs were still wrong. I either get `/callback` or `/rails/rails/callback`. Setting OmniAuth.config.full_host and manually crafting links was the only way I got the devise callbacks to work, and then I could manually create the functional route urls for /rails/callback